# How to exchange base docker images safely, when image is down?

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm learning Docker. Right now I'm working on a Django app and I want to make a container. I'm on Windows 10.

When I run `docker-compose build`, I get:

```
$ docker-compose build
Building movies
Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.8.2-alpine
3.8.2-alpine: Pulling from library/python
Service 'movies' failed to build: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.18363 in the manifest list entries
```

As far as I've investigated, I'm getting that error because the image is down (because of a bug of docker?)

a) https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/230

b) https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3835

**So what image can replace this one: FROM python:3.8.2-alpine???**

I'm following this tutorial `Test-Driven Development with Django, Django REST Framework, and Docker` from https://testdriven.io/.

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.2-alpine

# set work directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```